# Only file owners should be allowed to see the files they uploaded

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel

I've got an SFTP Server setup, and all users are jailed (chroot) to a specific directory (users are only allowed to upload to this single directory).

The requirement is to ensure that only the file owners can see their files; others don't get to see the files, even if they are in the same group.

Any recommendation on how to get this done on Linux or a code to write to get this done will be helpful. I was thinking there may be a configuration on Linux to get this done.

OS: Linux Fedora 5.14.10

Comment: It would be far too tedious to do this with a directory that everyone can access. The best thing to do, even though it would still require a bit more work, would be to create a subdirectory for each user to where they are the owner and set 700 permissions for them. That way, everyone can traverse into the directory but can only access the directory that they own which would do what you want.

Comment: If they are trapped in a directory, then how do they get out to see other files? (If they can't get to the other files, then what does it matter if they could read them if they could get to them?)

Comment: Consider their `umask`, or default permissions with ACLs (`setfacl`).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor From the description that is given, there's no concern that the users can get out of the directory and view or modify other files but rather that it's not wanted for them to be able to view files in the directory where they are locked other than those that they own.

Comment: To add to what I stated before, even if a subdirectory were created for each user and/or ACLs were applied, any user would still be able to change the permissions or ACLs to any files that they uploaded because they would be the owner. The same would also be true if the immutable attribute were set by some method on all of the files at creation. The only other thing that I can think of is to lock each user into their own directory from which they can't traverse when they get into the server. Any method would involve the same tedium as carving a giant spider out of ice with a chainsaw.

Comment: @NasirRiley "all users are jailed (chroot) to a specific directory".

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor That's my point. There doesn't appear to be any concern with them getting out of the directory. Where to the concern lies is with them being view files within the directory where they are locked.

Comment: @NasirRiley sorry I interpreted "there's no concern that the users can get out of the directory" as "does not care if the user can get out of the directory". Where as, I now think you meant "is assured that the user can not get out of the directory, but still has another concern".

Comment: Thanks all for the comment. 

However, the requirement is to ensure that all users can drop files to a single directory as that single directory is jailed and there are external services that require pulling the uploaded data from that directory. 

The security requirement is then to ensure that only the file owners can see the files they upload. No one else should be able to see the file if you are not the file owner or if you do not belong to a certain group or others if required.